# double dimension input only allows first row

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, double, dimensions

I have a double dimension array and my aim is to find the sum of all numbers and the sum of all numbers diagonally.

```
BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int [][] a=new int [5][5];
int same=0;
int sum=0;
System.out.println("Please enter your numbers");
for(int r=0;r<5;r++)
for(int c=0;r<5;r++)
a[r][c]=Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());   
for(int r=0;r<5;r++)
for(int c=0;r<5;r++)
sum=sum+a[r][c];
for(int r=0;r<5;r++)
for(int c=0;r<5;r++)
if (r==c)
{same=same+a[r][c];}

System.out.println("The sum of the diaganols is "+same+" The sum of everything is "+sum);
```

I've opened a double dimension array, but when I start the program I can only input 5 numbers, which correspond to the first row.

Im really new to programming, please forgive me for any stupid mistakes I meake, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because u are using the same variable in for loop for taking the input.

```
for(int r=0;r<5;r++)
//for r = 0
for(int c=0;r<5;r++)
//r 0 to 5 (take 5 input)
```

here r reaches 5 in inner loop so both the loop exit as the condition to exit is same for both (r<5). you should do something like below -:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++){
    a[i][j] = //read input
}
}
```